# Is there a clean way to access the local iteration scope of a generator expression?

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I am receiving a generator expression as an input argument to my function, and it looks like this:

```
(<some calculation> for item1 in list1)  # single iterator case
(<some calculation> for item1 in list1 for item2 in list2)  # multiple iterator case
```

The function is doing some internal stuff but in the end needs to return a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{item1: <calculated value>, ..}  # single case
{(item1, item2): <calculated value>, ..}  # multiple case
```

This works but I'd prefer to avoid messing around with what is obviously generator expression internals. Is there a clean way of making this work? I can imagine this could break in different versions of Python.

```
def to_dict(gen_expr):
    d = {}
    for x in gen_expr:
        local_vars = gen_expr.gi_frame.f_locals
        key = tuple(v for k, v in local_vars.items()
                    if k != ".0")  # ".0" points to the iterator object
        if len(key) == 1:
            key = key[0]
        d[key] = x
    return d
```

#### EDIT:

This works in the IPython console but running the same piece of code in the Anaconda prompt crashes on f_locals, which then suddenly also contains all objects from the generator code block. Because these objects are not (necessarily) hashable, it raises a TypeError on d[key] = x. So my fears about (ab)using generator internals were quickly confirmed.

Comment: Are you in control of the generator code?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Unfortunately not. If I would've, I'd definitely have avoided all this hacky stuff.